# Android 6.0 RS232 Communication Issue

Tags: android

I have an application running with API19. This application was using RS232 communication for transferring data. The communication(opening of port, transferring of data, closing port) was happening in native C/C++ language. I was loading the native code in Android application and was successfully able to transfer the data.
I updated my device to Android 6.0 some time back. Now the application is giving issues while opening the port. Is this an android permission issue? There were no special permissions required for RS232 communication in API19.
Any ideas?

Comment: Do you get any logcat output when running the app or when the error occurs? If yes please edit it in your question above.

Comment: Please, read [this (how to ask)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this (mcve)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before asking,
as those will help you get more and better answers from the community. Post your AndroidManifest, as well as check if the C binary fits the correct architeture of the device.[The documentation might help](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html)

Comment: Actually the RS232 communication is made by the underlying native code for which I am loading a shared object. Hence there is no Logcat output. The open command in native code is returning -1. My guess was its due to some permission issue in Android M.

Comment: The error it shows in native code log is "Permission Denied"